# How to embed authentication parameters in RTSP url for Quicktime

Tags: rtsp, quicktime

I've been searching the net to get some lead on how to embed authentication parameters in rtsp url for Quicktime, but haven't had any success. I'm beginning to wonder if Quicktime has support for it at all. I've installed QT 7.7 and have tried the following two methods for embedding username and password:

```
<OBJECT classid='clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B' width='200' height='156' codebase='http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab'>
    <param name='src' value='Loading.jpg'/>
    <param name='href' value='rtsp://address/archive/d8138017caf5c1?username=abcd&password=xyz'/>
    <param name='target' value='myself'/>
    <param name='autohref' value='true'/>
    <param name='controller' value='false'/>
    <EMBED type='application/x-rtsp' pluginspage='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/' width='200' height='156' src='Loading.jpg' href='rtsp://172.21.57.125/archive/d8138017caf5c1?username=apiuser&password=cisco' target='myself' autohref='true' controller='false' loop='false'>
    </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

In this case Quicktime fails to recognize the query parameters and brings up a dialog for username and password.

```
<OBJECT classid='clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B' width='200' height='156' codebase='http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab'>
    <param name='src' value='Loading.jpg'/>
    <param name='href' value='rtsp://username:password@address/archive/d8138017caf5c1'/>
    <param name='target' value='myself'/>
    <param name='autohref' value='true'/>
    <param name='controller' value='false'/>
    <EMBED type='application/x-rtsp' pluginspage='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/' width='200' height='156' src='Loading.jpg' href='rtsp://username:password@172.21.57.125/archive/d8138017caf5c1' target='myself' autohref='true' controller='false' loop='false'>
    </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

In the above case, Quicktime fails to play stating Server not found.

Is there a way to get authenticated rtsp streams to play in Quicktime ?